# Многие спрашивают, для чего мне это.

Tags: пунктуация

Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вполне нормально поставлена запятая между между главным и придаточным предложением

Comment: А вариант с двоеточием считаете неверным? Или тоже подходит?

Comment: Двоеточие разъясняет, поясняет, раскрывает содержания того, о чем говорится в первом предложении. Т.е. что именно спрашивают. Поэтому двоеточие вполне уместно здесь.

Comment: Против двоеточия я не буду активно возражать, но в этом случае в конце предложения нужно поставить вопросительный знак.

Comment: Остановлюсь ка я на запятой :) Спасибо за ответы!

Answer (score 0):

Многие спрашивают:  для чего мне это.